# "<frozen codecs>", line 319, in decode KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, input, output, keyboardinterrupt

i'm  learning input and output in python language, but whenever i try to let user input a value e.g age = input(9),class = input(7), it stops at the first statement not running the next statement and brings this  "", line 319, in decode
KeyboardInterrupt

age = input(10)
type_of_data = type(input(age))
print(type_of_data)
and i expect the reult to be: 10,<class 'str'> and 10